# How to prevent typing the same character the second time

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am doing a decimal number input validation where I want to prevent typing 'point' for the second consecutive time

For example- [image: Input field]

Above in the input box after keypress of the first period, I shouldn't be able to keypress it for the second consecutive time.

I have done this so far-

```
if (e.which === 190) {
   if(value === '') {
    e.preventDefault()
    this.setState({[error]: "Only one period allowed in decimal numbers!"});
    return false;
   }
}
```

But this only prevents the 3rd keypress and allows the second period.

How do I prevent the keypress using JavaScript?

PS- I am using input field if type- 'number'. So the after I press the second dot the e.target.value becomes null.

Comment: count the dots in the string. more than one? you're out.

Comment: If you want to be able to stop it, you must use the `keydown` event, because `keypress` is sent long after the input box has been updated.

Comment: @FedericoklezCulloca After the second dot, the value becomes null because it is of type number.

Comment: @some yes i am using onkeyDown and onKeyUp. But how i prevent the second dot?

Comment: If you want to stop it, yout only need to do it on `keydown`. Is `onkeyDown` a react thing, because otherwise it is named `onkeydown`?

Comment: @some yeah i am doing that on `onKeyDown`. But I need to allow the first dot and prevent the second dot. PS- After I type the second dot the value becomes null.

Comment: I'll do `str.replace("..", ".")` each time the `.` is pressed. I think there's no need for a "complicated" solution in this case.

Comment: @TakitIsy I am using ES6, so I can ignore `;`

Comment: @TakitIsy but how do you capture the `".."` ? As i said after i press dot for the second time the value becomes null.

Comment: @Boris, I see what you mean. Can you edit your post to get a working snippet reproducing your problem ?

Answer (score 2):

You can use regular expression alongwith `onChange` event.

```
testHanlder = (event) => {

  let value = event.target.value;

  if (value) {
    value = value.replace(/\.+/g, ".")
    this.setState({value})
  }
}
```

Comment: Value becomes null as soon as I type the second dot.

Comment: @RIYAH KHAN this works fine. Thanks alot :)
Just 1 observation- when i type dot for the second time the first dot is also removed.

Comment: @Boris I didn;t get that.In codesand box I did the same,its working fine

Answer (score 0):

Even if it passes the second decimal number issue, it will still allow alphabets inside the input field.
Instead you could use:-

```
var textBox = document.getElementById("txt")

textBox.addEventListener("keyup",function(e) {
  var floatValue = parseFloat(textBox.value) || ""
  if(floatValue !== textBox.value) textBox.value = floatValue
})
```